# Reading text from .text file and storing in array

Tags: java, arrays, file

so basically I only know how to read integers and store them in an array, but what about both Integers and words? Here is my code for doing just the integers from an array from an earlier time, the method is  readFileAndReturnWords.  How could I change it to read both integers and words as well?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

  public class WordsNsuch { 

     public static void main(String [ ] commandlineArguments){
        //Error message when arg is blank
        if(commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
        System.err.println("You did not enter anything");
        System.exit(0);
        }


         String[] array = readFileAndReturnWords(commandlineArguments[0]);
         sortAndPrintTheArray(array, commandlineArguments[0]);               
      }
      //RIGHT HERE GUYS
    public static String readFileAndReturnWords(String filename){
      String[] temp = new String[10000];
      int i = 0;    
      //connects file
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = null;

     try{

          inputFile = new Scanner(file);

         }
          //When arg is mistyped
      catch(FileNotFoundException Exception1) {
          System.out.println("File not found!");
          System.exit(0);      
     }


     //counts the amount of strings
    if (inputFile != null) {

    try {

      while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        try {
          temp[i] = inputFile.nextInt();//This is a problem
          i++;
        } catch (InputMismatchException Exception2) { 
          inputFile.next();
        }
      }
    } 
     finally {
      inputFile.close();
    }
    String[] array = new String[i];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, i);
    return array;
  }
  return new String[] {};
 }

  public static void sortAndPrintTheArray(String [] array, String filename){
       Sorting.display = false;
       Sorting.insertionSort(array, 0, array.length-1);//figure out how to get the last word later

      System.out.println("ASCII listing of words in file:\"" + filename + "\" = " + array.length);   
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("index = " + i + "," + " element = " + array[i]);

      }   
   }    
 }
```

Comment: you can use `inputFile.next()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going into your code but here is an example of how to read both numbers and words :

```
//while there's anything including numbers and words
    while(textfile.hasNext())
    {
       //if there's a number, read it!
       if(textfile.hasNextInt())
           {
               int number = textfile.nextInt(); //it can be double, float..
           }
       else 
            textfile.next()
       String word1 = textfile.hasNext();
       String word2 = textfile.hastNext();

       f(textfile.hasNextInt())
           {
               int number2 = textfile.nextInt(); //it can be double, float..
           }
       else 
            textfile.next()
       .......
    }
```

Anytime if there's a number, try if-else statement ("else" statement depends on how big and how full your textfile is with numbers and letters) but when after a number there follows a String use else statement similar to the else statement in the code that I've mentioned; when there's a String, just read that with textfileName.hasNext() w/o any conditionals. Any question, do not hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code snippet to help you out, I have based it on your code.

I would handle the arrays slightly differently but I just want to point you in the right direction, not do the work for you.

This will create two arrays: *ints* and *strs* one staininging the integers and one containing the strings.

```
int[] ints = new int[10000];
String[] strs = new String[10000];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

File file = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = null;

try {
  inputFile = new Scanner(file);
} catch(FileNotFoundException Exception1) {
  System.out.println("File not found!");
  System.exit(0);      
}

try {
  while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    if (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
      ints[i++] = inputFile.nextInt();
    } else {
      strs[j++] = inputFile.next();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!